# How to deal with redirects with nginx reverse proxy

Tags: docker, nginx, redirect

Hey i am trying to run a network of couple of docker containers with one accessible point which is an Nginx container. So users connect to one container and based on their url they get different webpages which are served from different containers.

Note: only the nginx container is accessible to the public. and the destination container url `jackett:9117`, is accessible from within the nginx container.

my issue is htat one container has an internal redirect that doesn't go well with my `proxy_pass` configuration on nginx.

here is the nginx config and the compose config for the container :

```
    location /jackett {
      proxy_pass http://jackett:9117/;
    }
```

```
  jackett:
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/jackett
    container_name: jackett
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=Europe/London
      - AUTO_UPDATE=true #optional
    volumes:
      - ./jackett/downloads:/downloads
    restart: unless-stopped
```

the jackett container (the container with the redirect exposes port 9117) redirects to `/UI/Dashboard` when you call the `/` url. for my configuration this will endup calling
`/UI/Dashboard` on the nginx container that has no location configured for that. (the browser url would switch to `domain/UI/Dashboard` after calling `domain/jackett`)

the container has a lot of redirects like this one, so tackling them one by one seems not feasible.

What can i do to fix this within the nginx config? i tried intercepting the redirectsbut didn't know what to do afterwards ( based on [this](https://gist.github.com/sirsquidness/710bc76d7bbc734c7a3ff69c6b8ff591) )

Comment: Any luck on this issue?

Comment: @Ryan Not really, my project just sat there with this error.